# How rating system works?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, rating-system

i want to make rating system for my website using codeigniter and MySQL. Can any one tell me how rating system works? what are the calculations in rating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a star rating then you need to count the votes and the rating. A special case is when you get high votes or very few votes then the problem is how do you sort the votes. A solution would be to write an algorithm that can find wrong or illegal votes and compute a meaningful ranking. Here is an implementation of the Wilson intervall that solve this equation: [Star rating, implementing Wilson score interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467062/star-rating-implementing-wilson-score-interval).